# nullpointerexception in processing when running this program

Tags: java, processing

```
import java.util.Arrays.*;
int size=100;
//Student[] stud;
//SeatingChart[][] seats;
ArrayList<Student> roster;
void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);

  roster = new ArrayList<Student>();
  roster.add(new Student("Jin", 3));
  roster.add(new Student("Alta", 11));
  roster.add(new Student("Paul", 9));
  roster.add(new Student("Piar", 1));
  roster.add(new Student("Terra", 1));
  roster.add(new Student("Ayako", 9));
  roster.add(new Student("Glen", 2));
  roster.add(new Student("Fran", 1));
  roster.add(new Student("David", 4));
  roster.add(new Student("Danny", 3));
  SeatingChart apcs = new SeatingChart(roster, 5, 5);
  apcs.removeAbsentStudents(6, roster);
  apcs.drawChart(roster);
}




public class Student 
{ 
  private String name;
  private int absenceCount;

  public Student ( String nm )
  {  
    name = nm;
  }

  public Student ( String nm, int count )
  {  
    name = nm; 
    absenceCount = count;
  }

  public void setAbsenceCount( int ac )
  {   
    absenceCount = ac;
  }

  public String getName()  
  {  
    return name;
  }

  public int getAbsenceCount() 
  {  
    return absenceCount;
  } 

  public String toString()
  {  
    return name + " " + absenceCount + " ";
  }
}

public class SeatingChart
{
  private Student[][] seats; 
  public SeatingChart(ArrayList<Student> studentList, int rows, int cols)
  {
    seats = new Student[rows][cols];

    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size (); i++)
    {
      seats[row][col] = studentList.get(i);
      row++;
      if (row == rows)
      {
        row = 0;
        col++;
      }
    }
  }
  void drawChart(ArrayList<Student> newSeatingChart)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<6; j++) {
        stroke(0);
        fill(255);
        rect(i*size, j*size, size, size);
        fill(0);
        stroke(0);
        for (int k=0; k<newSeatingChart.size (); i++) {
          text(newSeatingChart.get(i).name, i*size, j*size);
          text(newSeatingChart.get(i).absenceCount, i*size+40, j*size);
        }
      }
    }
  }


  /** Removes students who have more than a given number of absences from the
   * seating chart, replacing those entries in the seating chart with null
   * and returns the number of students removed.
   * @param allowedAbsences an integer >= 0
   * @return number of students removed from seats
   * Postcondition:
   * - All students with allowedAbsences or fewer are in their original positions in seat
   * - No student in seats has more than allowedAbsences absences.
   * - Entries without students contain null.
   */
  public int removeAbsentStudents(int allowedAbsences, ArrayList<Student> l)
  {
    int removedCount = 0; 
    for (int r = 0; r < seats.length; r++)
    {
      for (int c = 0; c < seats[0].length; c++)
      {
        l.set(r, seats[r][c]);
        if (seats[r][c] != null && seats[r][c].getAbsenceCount() > allowedAbsences)
        {
          seats[r][c] = null;
          removedCount++;
        }
      }
    }
    return removedCount;
  }

  /** Rearrange students in the seating chart in alphabetical order
   * with a new set of rows and columns
   * and returns the new seating chart. The original seating chart
   * is not affected.
   * @param rows - may be different from the original number of rows
   * @param col - may be different from the original number of columns
   * Postcondition:
   * - All students with be in the new seating chart
   * - The original seating chart is the same
   */
  public Student[][] rearrangedStudents(int rows, int cols)
  {
    Student[][] updatedList=new Student[rows][cols];
    for (int i=0; i<seats[0].length; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<seats.length; j++) {
        if (seats[i][j].name.charAt(0)<seats[i+1][j+1].name.charAt(0)) {
          seats[i][j]=seats[i+1][j+1];
          seats[i+1][j+1]=seats[i][j];
        }
      }
    }
    return updatedList;
  }

  public String toString()
  { 
    return "";
  }
}
```

The issue is that, after executing. It will show the student class header and highlight the line private String name;. I am not sure why this is as it is a class. I have also properly used it. as you can see with the constructors. So can, someone fix this code or tell me how I should fix it?

Comment: Please add a stack trace to the question.

Comment: @KevinO what is a stack trace?

Comment: Note: This is using the Processing editor, which isn't giving a stack trace. The user has actually provided all of the information they have. This isn't a Java question, it's a Processing question. Processing has its own editor, and that's what we're talking about here.

Comment: @KevinWorkman, Thanks. Didn't catch that nuance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Processing editor isn't always great at providing feedback. It's telling you that you're getting a `NullPointerException`, and it's trying to guess where that exception is happening.

The problem is, what it's telling you is wrong. The line that's highlighted is not where the `NullPointerException` is happening. In fact, an exception **can't** occur on that line.

This is because Processing first has to compile your Processing code into Java code, and it's not a one-to-one mapping. It then runs that Java code, which is where your `NullPointerException` is happening. But it can't always go back and tell you where in your Processing code the cause of the exception is. In other words: **take the line it's highlighting with a grain of salt**.

However, something in your code is indeed causing a `NullPointerException`. This is why it's always a good idea to do **incremental debugging**. Instead of writing your entire project and then testing it, you should write **one small part** and test that. I usually test **every time I add a line of code**. Test often. That way you'll know exactly what line causes an exception.

For your case, honestly, if I were you I'd start over with a clean sketch. Then try copying **one small part** over into that sketch. Run that. Test it with print statements. If that works how you'd expect it to, then add the next small part. Repeat that process until you hit the `NullPointerException`, and then you'll know exactly what line of Processing code is causing the problem.